# Access localhost of another computer

Tags: networking, port

We are not on the same network. Website uses WebRTC and Janus-Gateway. I tryed using ngrok and tools like that. But even if i point ngrok to janus-gateway and it CAN connect, webrtc data still doesn't send.

What would be a solution for this?

Thanks!

P.S I am accessing the other computer Trough RDP(Remmina), maybe that could be of some use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved(was problem in my endpoint urls).